# ERROR delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted(hadoop window10)

Tags: hadoop, resourcemanager

I use windows 10 and node manager also not starting correctly. I see the following errors:

```
Resource manager is not connecting and failing due to :
2021-07-07 11:01:52,473 ERROR delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: ExpiredTokenRemover received java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
2021-07-07 11:01:52,493 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@756b58a7{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/cluster}
2021-07-07 11:01:52,504 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped ServerConnector@633a2e99{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8088}
2021-07-07 11:01:52,504 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7b420819{/static,jar:file:/F:/hadoop_new/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-3.2.1.jar!/webapps/static,UNAVAILABLE}
2021-07-07 11:01:52,507 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@c9d0d6{/logs,file:///F:/hadoop_new/logs/,UNAVAILABLE}
2021-07-07 11:01:52,541 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8033
2021-07-07 11:01:52,543 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8033
2021-07-07 11:01:52,544 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2021-07-07 11:01:52,544 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2021-07-07 11:01:52,550 INFO resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2021-07-07 11:01:52,554 FATAL resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: 5: Access is denied.
```

and

```
2021-07-07 11:01:51,625 INFO recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2021-07-07 11:01:52,158 INFO store.AbstractFSNodeStore: Created store directory :file:/tmp/hadoop-yarn-Abby/node-attribute
2021-07-07 11:01:52,186 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeAttributesManagerImpl failed in state STARTED
5: Access is denied.

        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.store.AbstractFSNodeStore.recoverFromStore(AbstractFSNodeStore.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.FileSystemNodeAttributeStore.recover(FileSystemNodeAttributeStore.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesManagerImpl.initNodeAttributeStore(NodeAttributesManagerImpl.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesManagerImpl.serviceStart(NodeAttributesManagerImpl.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:1262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1299)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.transitionToActive(ResourceManager.java:1299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1535)
2021-07-07 11:01:52,212 INFO service.AbstractService: Service RMActiveServices failed in state STARTED
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: 5: Access is denied.

        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:105)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:1262)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1299)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.transitionToActive(ResourceManager.java:1299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1350)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1535)
Caused by: 5: Access is denied.

        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1098)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:987)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.store.AbstractFSNodeStore.recoverFromStore(AbstractFSNodeStore.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.FileSystemNodeAttributeStore.recover(FileSystemNodeAttributeStore.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesManagerImpl.initNodeAttributeStore(NodeAttributesManagerImpl.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.nodelabels.NodeAttributesManagerImpl.serviceStart(NodeAttributesManagerImpl.java:123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:194)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *access denied*, maybe need to run with another user. Try to start services with a user with more access like Administrator in windows.